# Proving that the set of Integers is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra

My professor taught us this proof that the set of integers is infinite:

Suppose $Z$ is not infinite, therefore there is a number $m\in N$ such that exists a bijection $f:Im\rightarrow Z$. That means $f^{-1}:Z\rightarrow Im$ is also a bijection, but if we pick $n \in N$ such that $n>m$, $In\subset Z$, the restricted function $f^{-1}|_{In} : In\rightarrow Im$ is still an injection which is a contradiction, since there can't be an injection with a domain that has more elements than the codomain, therefore Z is infinite.

However I can't understand why we can assume $In\subset Z$ when we already said $Z$ has $m$ elements and $In$ has more than $m$ elements.

Ps: Sorry about my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: "there can't be an injection with a domain that has more elements than the codomain" is false depending on how "more" is defined. The canonical $\Bbb Z > 2\Bbb Z$ demonstrates why.

Comment: We were studying finite sets, as in a set A is finite if there is a bijection from $Im$ to A, $Im$={$x \in N$/$1\le x\le m$}, so a set B would have more elements than A if there was a bijection from $In$ to B and n>m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deduction

$$f^{-1} : \mathbb Z \to I_m \ \text{ exists and is a bijection } \Longrightarrow f^{-1}|_{I_n} :  I_n \to I_m \ \text{ exists and is an injection }$$

itself is sound.

The nub of your complaint is what leads to the contradiction: there cannot be such an $f^{-1}$ nor such an $f$.

In other words, you are demonstrating the logical inconsistency in a different way that the argument is written. It is not surprising that you can deduce a logical contradiction from one step of the chain of reasoning. The chain of reasoning is written to ultimately demonstrate such a contradiction.  Either way (*the way the argument is written* or *the logical inconsistency you found*), we arrive at the desired contradiction and necessarily conclude that the starting premise is false.

Comment: I still don't understand, why is that deduction sound? How can I say there is a bijection from a finite set to another, but then restrict the domain to a finite set that has more elements than the domain? 
 Ps: I forgot to explain what $In$ and $Im$ means, I explained it now in a comment to my question.

Comment: Remember that a deduction from a false statement to a false statement is can still be a valid deduction. Look at the deduction I have written above. It  has to be valid, just by simple laws of what a function means, as applied to the function $f^{-1}$. If $f^{-1}$ exists and is a bijection, then clearly $f^{-1}$ applied to a restricted domain exists and will be an injection.

Comment: Okay I get why that deduction is valid, I still don't understand fully though. [I think] the point of a proof by contradiction is to assume something we know is false as true, then apply known theorems until we get something that's false. I understand everything up to $f^{-1}:Z\rightarrow Im$. Then we assume $In\subset Z$, why?

Comment: We do so to arrive at a contradiction. Certainly $I_n$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: (And to clarify: the basic strategy of proof by contradiction of a statement $A$ is to assume $not \ A$ and show that leads to some logical inconsistency. Then conclude that as $not \ A$ is false it must be the case that $not \ ( \ not \ A) = A$ is true. E.g., the standard proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask why is $I_n$ a subset of Z?

Comment: $I_n$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z$ for every positive integer $n$. If it were not, then there would be an integer $p$ with $1 \leq p \leq n$ which is not in $\mathbb Z$, which is itself a contradiction.

Comment: But you're assuming Z is infinite to say that, but we started the proof saying Z was not infinite. That's what I was thinking, we start by assuming Z is not infinite, then we assume something because we already know it's infinite($I_n \subset Z$), to prove it is infinite. Basically "it is infinite because it is infinite", that's what I'm understanding of this.

Comment: The choice of $n$ does rely on the idea that there is no highest integer. That is, given $m$ there always exists another integer $n$ such that $n > m$. What the proof is doing is turning that notion of 'an infinity in order', an ordinal infinity, implies 'an infinity of size', a cardinal infinity. That is an important distinction worth keeping straight. So in one sense you are right: "it is infinite because it is infinite". Except the infinites are different.

Comment: Ah I got it now, thank you very much!
(Little bit more info: My confusion was a mix up of two things
1: I (embarrassingly) forgot that Z is a specific set with rules that we can use independently if we assume it's infinite or not
2: I was thinking "why do we need to prove Z is infinite if we can already say that $I_n\subset Z $ for every positive integer n", which you answered by saying it's because there are different types of infinites.)

Comment: Great.  *Correction to my convoluted sentence above:* What the proof is doing is **showing** that ...